# Android Tablet UI : multi-pane fragment or linear layout

Tags: android-layout, android-fragments, android, master-detail

I need to create app that will initially work only for tablets. I'm aware of the “List-and-Detail” pattern in which there’s a list of something, where clicking on the list brings up details on the item that was clicked upon.

That’s just perfect as long as all the layouts always have two panes: one for the list of items and one for the detail of the selected item.

Well, in my app I want to use the first pane that is usually used for the list of items as the menu of all the available option in the app and the second pane, the one that takes up most of the available space, to show a specific layout based on the option that was selected in the first fragment.

The problem is that the second pane will not always be composed of a single part.

These are all the possible scenarios I will have(the left part with the red frame represents the menu that should always be displayed):

**1.    Details pane composed by a single part:**

[image]

**2.    Details pane composed by two parts of the same size, which do not have a master-detail relationship.**

[image]

**3.    Details pane composed by two parts, which do have a mater-detail relationship, but the master part is wider than the details part**

### #Edit :

Since the main goal of my app is to help waiters take orders, this third scenario comes into play when:

- The waiter selects the option "Take order" from the left menu (let's pretend it's the "Item two" in the image)
- In the first part of the details pane, the waiter can choose among all the categories of food they serve (pretend it's the list at the top) and according to the category selected, the below list shows all the dishes under that specific category.
- Once the waiter taps on a dish it's automatically added to the second part of the details pane (the one that is hidden in the first scenario)

[image]

**4.    Details pane composed by two parts, which do have a mater-detail relationship, but the details part is wider than the master part.**

[image]

I know that if want to reuse the layout from different size of screens and orientations I have to use fragments, but have to determine on the fly one to show two or one part (fragments) in the details pane or which part will be wider than the other seems like a lot of work and to be honest I’m not sure how to do it since all I know now is that the main activity, the one with the slots for the menu pane and the details pane should be similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/menu"
android:layout_weight="30"
android:layout_width="0px"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
/>
<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/content"
android:layout_weight="70"
android:layout_width="0px"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Do you think you could give some UI guidelines here? Maybe I’m over thinking all this I should go with a single linear layout with the number of parts I need.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I kind of understood what you want, but am also confused. Where are you facing your problem exactly? Is it with determining how to assign size of "first part" in detail screen a different size? If yes, i guess, it will be nice to have a fixed size for the first part and second part as this will not spoil the user experience. Changing sizes will be have a bad user experience. If you are asking on how to add two layouts in the detail screen, then i think the answer is use two FrameLayouts and replace them dynamically. Didn't work on this scenario before. But may be it will work..

Comment: @VamsiChalla Thank you very much for taking the time to take a look a my question. Well, the problem I have is that I don't know how divide the "details" pane, because as you can see, depending on the item selected on the menu, it can have one or two parts? I want to use fragments so that I can reuse those fragment for portrait orientation, but then the question is, should I use three `FrameLayout`? If so, how do I hide the third `FrameLayout` when it is not needed? How do I resize them so that they accommodate to the available space?

Comment: You didn't mention how you plan to change around the different details layouts according to orientation(for example what happens with scenario 2 with the two details part when you're in portrait orientation?). You could  keep the master-detail template and for the (different)details part use a wrapper fragment with the actual content being nested two fragments. That way , in the wrapper fragment you could change the part like you want(and basically having a mini master-details relationship).

Comment: Let's talk about DetailScreen. This is what i think will work.. Use two FrameLayouts with layout_weight="1" for both. I am not sure about the logic on when you will have two FrameLayouts visible and when one FrameLayout is visible, but depending on when you need to show 2 or 1, you can set the visibility of the second FrameLayout to View.GONE or View.VISIBLE, so that if the second FrameLayout is hidden, the first FrameLayout will take the entire space available and that way, it will span the whole DetailScreen. As you might be aware, use the FrameLayout's id, to set visibility of that Fragment

Comment: If you want to have different sizes for the first and second FrameLayouts in DetailScreen, use respective weights, for example, layout_weight="0.60" and "0.40" for first and second FrameLayouts respectively. That way, you will be splitting the DetailScreen into 3:2 ratio. I think you are already aware of this, but just in case you need it.

Comment: @Luksprog Well, I didn't mention that before because this app is initially being targeted for tablets only in landscape orientation, but we've got portrait orientation and a version for phones in mind too, so now that you mention it, I guess that we could use some sort of tabs or a `ViewPager` for that specific scenario. Yes, I think that thing you mention about the wrapper fragment might be what I'm looking for. Do you think you could give an example or link me to some resources?

Comment: @VamsiChalla My initial idea was to use `DrawerLayout` for the menu and somehow try to use two `FrameLayout`s for the actual content(hiding and showing the second `FrameLayout` according to the selected item on the menu) But then I read a couple of questions on SO recommending not to use `DrawerLayout` for tablets in landscape orientation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you seen the [**Retrieving a List of Contacts**](http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html) example ? Here they have shown how to properly implement multi-pane master-detail flow. The same code provides a multi-pane landscape layout on tablets, and a single-pane portrait layout on normal handsets. It is an interesting, though slightly complicated, example.

About having three panes in some cases: I don't think this is a great idea. I think that at any given time there should be only one list screen and one detail screen, and you should implement your app's UI flow to support such an idiom. It would not be very difficult to implement a three-pane layout, but I doubt it would be useful or innovative.

**EDIT:**

I've understood your requirement, and I have to admit that I did not realize the possibility of this type of usage. Its a good design. What I feel is, you don't really need to think in terms of *three* panes: rather, treat the left list as the list-pane, and the entire right side as a single detail-pane. Inside this one detail-pane, you can have three nested `Fragment`s for the three separate regions. Or instead, since nested `Fragment`s can sometimes create more problems than they solve, let there be three `LinearLayout`s. That would be easier to handle, What I am trying to do is simplify the layout so that it works properly and without complicated code.

Comment: Thank you @ZygoteInit. I'll definitely take a look at that sample. Now regarding to your comment on not being a good idea to use a multiple pane approach. Well, I couldn't agree more with you and if I could/knew how to avoid it, believe me, I would.

Comment: it is not *multi-pane* that I am against, rather having more than two ... has your project manager told you that you *must* use a three-pane layout ?

Comment: No, not all. It's jut that having all the space that is available in tablet in landscape orientation, I thought I had to make the most of it. So I decided to use two parts when considered necessary. I'll try describe the third scenario in the original question.

Comment: I've updated my question to provide more details about what I consider it necessary to have three panes for the third scenario. Please take a look at the "Edit" part in my question.

Comment: Yep that's exactly what I thought and that's the reason of my question's title. I wanted to use LinearLayout for the details pane in the third scenario, but then again, if I used that approach, I wouldn't be able to reuse the part with categories/dishes(on the left) and the part with the list of the orders for a specific customer (on the right) when I want to change orientation to portrait in a tablet or use the app on phones.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I believe that this is a good case for a tablet-only application. I think the UI is perfect for tablets and would be very convenient to use on tablets. Opposite would be the case with normal phones, I think. Does this project require you to develope an app for tablets AND handsets ? Perhaps you should speak to your project manager about this, that it would not be that great on handsets .... what do you think ?

Comment: Yes I think that making the app available only for tablets will the _best_ way to go, but even if it is a tablet-only app, it will have to consider orientation changes and I think that in portrait orientation I will only be able to handle one pane at the time. Or should I consider disabling screen rotations so that only landscape orientation is available?

Comment: Would you mind if I waited a couple of days in case someone else wants to answer. Some people might consider it unnecessary to respond to a question with an accepted answer.

Comment: @eddy: where have you reached with this ?

Comment: Sorry @Zygoteinit it's just that was trying something completely different. Here http://goo.gl/6lkxNE. Please don't get me wrong. I really appreciate all your help. It's just that I wanted to try other options and see what suits me better. Hope you understand.

Answer (score 1):

What I got from your question is that you want to set different layout weight for different situations right? If it is so then you can do it programmatically, also you want to hide your layout for first case so use 3 layouts for menu, content1 and content2 hide content2 for first case as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/menu"
android:layout_weight="30"
android:layout_width="0px"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
/>
<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/content2"
android:layout_width="0px"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
/>
<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/content2"
android:layout_width="0px"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

For first case use:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsmenu = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,   LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
paramsmenu.weight = 30f;
FrameLayout frameLayoutmenu = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.menu);
frameLayoutmenu.setLayoutParams(paramsmenu);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,   LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
params1.weight = 70f;
FrameLayout frameLayoutContent1 = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.content1);
frameLayoutContent1.setLayoutParams(params1);
FrameLayout frameLayoutContent2 = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.content2);
frameLayoutContent2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

For second case use:

```
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsmenu = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,   LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    paramsmenu.weight = 30f;
    FrameLayout frameLayoutmenu = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.menu);
    frameLayoutmenu.setLayoutParams(paramsmenu);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,   LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    params1.weight = 35f;
    FrameLayout frameLayoutContent1 = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.content1);
    frameLayoutContent1.setLayoutParams(params1);
    FrameLayout frameLayoutContent2 = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.content2);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,   LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    params2.weight = 35f;
    frameLayoutContent2.setLayoutParams(params2);
```

For third case use:

```
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsmenu = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,   LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    paramsmenu.weight = 30f;
    FrameLayout frameLayoutmenu = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.menu);
    frameLayoutmenu.setLayoutParams(paramsmenu);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,   LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    params1.weight = 40f;
    FrameLayout frameLayoutContent1 = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.content1);
    frameLayoutContent1.setLayoutParams(params1);
    FrameLayout frameLayoutContent2 = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.content2);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,   LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    params2.weight = 30f;
    frameLayoutContent2.setLayoutParams(params2);
```

For fourth case use:

```
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsmenu = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,   LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    paramsmenu.weight = 30f;
    FrameLayout frameLayoutmenu = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.menu);
    frameLayoutmenu.setLayoutParams(paramsmenu);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,   LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    params1.weight = 20f;
    FrameLayout frameLayoutContent1 = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.content1);
    frameLayoutContent1.setLayoutParams(params1);
    FrameLayout frameLayoutContent2 = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.content2);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,   LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    params2.weight = 50f;
    frameLayoutContent2.setLayoutParams(params2);
```